# Listing bluetooth Devices in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, bluetooth

Noticed that an Android Lollipop phone will be visible to nearby bluetooth devices only when Bluetooth Settings screen is Open. My usecase was to launch the app on a phoneA from PhoneB using Insecure bluetooth connection which now doesnt work because PhoneA doesnt even show in the bluetooth list. Also there is no option to set Visibility Timeout. Any hints ?

In another scenario, i turn on bluetooth via Intent within my app and PhoneA shows up on PhoneB but successful connection is not built. Successful connection will be built only when PhoneA Bluetooth Settings screen is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, we used [Enabling Bluetooth Discovery](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability) to serve my purpose. Thanks all.